# How do I count all the other nodes related to a specific node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

The path is representing for users' browse **history**.

The upper path means there's one user who has browsed **page A -> page B -> page C**

The lower path means, one user browsed **page X-> page Y -> page B -> page C**

For example, If I want to calculate the **relevance** with **page C**

The expected anwser is on the table

[image]

Or if I want to find all the relevance with **page B**

the anwser should be

- page A : 1
- page X : 1
- page Y : 1
- page C : **0**

How could I get the expected anwser with **py2neo** or  **cypher query**

Comment: are the two B nodes the same ? or these are distinct in the database ?

Comment: YES the two B nodes are identical in the same DB

Comment: ha ok, I'll change my answer then :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your "b" nodes are different nodes, and thus you have complete distinct paths, this query works :

```
MATCH (b:Page)
WHERE b.id = 'b'
MATCH (b)<-[:LINK_TO*..10]-(referer)
RETURN referer.id, count(*)
```

Result :

```
y   1
a   1
x   1
```

Test console here http://console.neo4j.org/r/sb5qmq

Change `'b'` by `c` to see that b will have a count of 2

```
b   2
y   1
a   1
x   1
```

**EDIT**

If your nodes 'b' are the same, you can do this :

```
MATCH (b:Page { id:'b' })
WITH b
MATCH (p:Page)
WHERE p <> b
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[r:LINK_TO*..3]->(b)
RETURN p.id, count(r)
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/prb2my

Comment: thanks so much. i'm new to here, your explination is so clear